# C# JIRA work-log update error "The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

Tags: c#, curl, httpwebrequest, jira, jira-rest-api

Im going to update work log of an issue in JIRA via the JIRA REST API on c# application. Following codes shows what I have done so far.

**HttpWebResponse** return this error **"The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."**.

I tried this with same credentials and using same data in PHP cURL functions, it works fine and issue work log updated successfully.

This is my Jason converted serialized object : **{"update":{"worklog":[{"add":{"comment":"Sample test comment by IJ","timeSpent":"210"}}]}}**

```
protected string RunQuery(JiraResource resource, string argument = null, string data = null, string method = "PUT")
{
// Where;
// resource = issue
// argument = "JIRA-16"
// Data = {"update":{"worklog":[{"add":{"comment":"Sample test comment by IJ","timeSpent":"210"}}]}}
// Method = "PUT"

        string url = string.Format("{0}{1}/", m_BaseUrl, resource.ToString());

        if (argument != null)
        {
            url = string.Format("{0}{1}", url, argument);
        }

// URL = https://companyname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/JIRA-16

        HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        request.ContentType = "application/json";
        request.Method = method;
        request.ContentLength = data.Length;

        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            writer.Write(data);
        }

        string base64Credentials = GetEncodedCredentials(); // check below
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Credentials);

        HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;// here returns the error
//The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

        string result = string.Empty;
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }

        return result;
}

private string GetEncodedCredentials()
{
        string mergedCredentials = string.Format("{0}:{1}", m_Username, m_Password);
        byte[] byteCredentials = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mergedCredentials);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(byteCredentials);
}
```

Where am I doing wrong? please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Likely reason: you are adding authorization header *after* sending request stream.

```
   var request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
   request.ContentType = "application/json";
   request.Method = method;
   request.ContentLength = data.Length;

   // All headers MUST be added before writing to request stream
   request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + GetEncodedCredentials());

   using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
   {
       writer.Write(data);
   }
```